# Baby-friendly trek near Innsbruck

Tags: hiking, children, alps, austria, huts

My family is going to Innsbruck in August, and we want to do a 3-4 day mountain hut trek. This will be our first trek with our son, who will be 16 months old. I can see many, many huts and trails in the area, but I'm having a hard time ascertaining which ones are easier. For example, we don't want via ferrata, nor very steep climbs. Basically, we just want an easy trek - I'm sure that practically anywhere in the area will be lovely, we don't need somewhere [famous.](http://stubaier-hoehenweg.at/en/som/hoehenweg.1.htm/)

I don't mind arriving in Innsbruck and then consulting with locals, but I'm worried that things will be crazy in August, and if I don't reserve places in huts, they will fill up. Is this true?

Anyone have a route or area they'd like to suggest?

Comment: Traditionally, huts accept anyone who arrives, but you may not have a bed.  If you arrive by 3pm or so, you probably will.

Answer (score 4):

Why not try the Wilder Kaiser, it's not in Innsbruck, only some 55mins drive, but it's pretty dame awesome and very kid friendly! More than 400km of walking paths make the Wilder Kaiser mountains an absolute gem for hiking holidays. Trails include accurate directions and approximate walk times.

**Hiking from hut to hut**

There is a remarkably diverse paradise just waiting to be discovered when hiking in the Wilder Kaiser region. The variety of tours is huge and the combination of mild climate, fresh mountain air and steady physical activity has a wonderfully revitalising effect on the body. Why not prolong the experience and enjoy some traditional Austrian hospitality along the way with a 3 days' hut-to-hut hike. This tour takes you to the prettiest spots on the south side of the range where, thanks to the moderate altitude, the tour can be enjoyed from as early as June until mid October.

Source: http://www.austria.info/uk/things-to-do/walking-and-hiking/hiking-wilder-kaiser

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to post what we ended up doing here, so I'll do that now (better late than never)

Basically, we slept two nights in [Hottinger Alm](https://hoettingeralm.at/english/), which is really close to Innsbruck. We took the "Nordkette” to Hungersberg, and from there we walked to Umbruggler Alm, had lunch, and continued on to Hottinger Alm. It's uphill, but the stop along the way made it reasonable. A few hours walking altogether.

We made two short side trips to Bodensteinhutte (which has facilities, i.e. food) and to Achselboden Hut (which doesn't). We walked back to Innsbruck via a gentle biking path, stopping on the way to have lunch at Arzler Alm.

All of this was done with my son on my back.

Another thing we did, which wasn't in Innsbruck, was to do two trips from  Pertisau (we took a train+bus to get there). On one day we bicycled to Gramai Alm (we rented bicycles and a carriage for our son) and on another we walked to Pletzachalm. This area is even easier to walk with kids, because the trails are paved, so you can even take them with a stroller.